# Using Filter Function to categorize list by specific index + Printing by specific index or list name

Tags: python, list, function, filter, categories

I am creating and manipulating a list in Python, I am having trouble categorizing my lists via filter function...

I have 3 lists, that I append into one list, I frequently print (the_list) along the way, here is my code:

```
list1 = ['Georgia', 10.5, 'Peach'];
list2 = ['Florida', 21.3, 'Sunshine'];
list3= ['Alabama', 4.9, 'Dixie'];

#List that includes list1, list2 and list3 called "the_list"
the_list = []
the_list.append(list1)
the_list.append(list2)
the_list.append(list3)
the_list

#insert new values into the list (these values represent state numbers)
list1.insert(3, 4)
list2.insert(3, 27)
list3.insert(3, 22)

#print the modified list
print (the_list)

#Organize the list from lowest to highest (based off numbers in index 1)
the_list.sort(key=lambda tup: tup[1])

print (the_list)

#filter states by category based off their population
#This is where I need help

#Small States
def lessThanTen(index):
return index < 10
the_list

filter(lessThanTen, the_list)

print (the_list)

#Big States
def greaterThanTen(index):
    return index > 10
    the_list

filter(greaterThanTen, the_list)

print (the_list)
```

Is there a way to filter these lists into categories by a specific index number, in this case index [1] (Which is population), and subsequently output these list items by printing, either their list name or their value at index [0]...example 'Georgia' or "list1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pass index as argument and maintain some flexibility of your list (you may have population at index other than 1), you can do this

```
def greaterThanTen(index):
    return lambda x: x[index] > 10

def lessThanTen(index):
    return lambda x: x[index] < 10

def myfilter(f, L):
    return [x[0] for x in filter(f, L)]

print(myfilter(greaterThanTen(1), the_list)) # -> ['Georgia', 'Florida']
print(myfilter(lessThanTen(1), the_list))    # -> ['Alabama']
```

Or more generically,

```
import operator

def index_vs_num(index):
    ops = {
           '>' : operator.gt,
           '<' : operator.lt,
           '>=': operator.ge,
           '<=': operator.le,
           '=' : operator.eq
          }
    return lambda relation: lambda num: lambda x: ops[relation](x[index], num)

greaterThanTwenty = index_vs_num(1)('>')(20) 
# the 1st argument is index of your population in the list
# the 2nd argument is the type of comparation 
# the 3rd argument is the number to be compared
lessThanFive =  index_vs_num(1)('<')(5)

def filter_by_outindex(*index):
    def filter_by_f(f, L):
        try:
            return [x[index[0]] for x in filter(f, L)]
        except IndexError:
            return list(filter(f, L))
    return filter_by_f

myfilter=filter_by_outindex(0)

print(myfilter(greaterThanTwenty, the_list)) # -> ['Florida']
print(myfilter(lessThanFive, the_list))   # -> ['Alabama']
```

I think this is what you actually want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

[Python filter documentation:](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter)

> filter(function, iterable) **Construct an iterator from those elements
>   of iterable for which function returns true.** iterable may be either a
>   sequence, a container which supports iteration, or an iterator. If
>   function is None, the identity function is assumed, that is, all
>   elements of iterable that are false are removed.
>
> Note that filter(function, iterable) is equivalent to the generator
>   expression (item for item in iterable if function(item)) if function
>   is not None and (item for item in iterable if item) if function is
>   None.

It's unclear what you mean, but I'll try to help you the best I can.

**First of all**: you're `greaterThanTen` function takes `index` as input, at least it looks that way. `filter` doesn't pass index as an argument to `greaterThanTen`, but rather the element at that index.

**Another thing:** I don't know if you understand that `filter` only returns one 'category' as output -- you can only sort one condition at a time. Also, filter doesn't operate on the original list, but creates a new sequence, so `filter(greaterThanTen, the_list)` doesn't actually change anything. What you should do is: `the_list = filter(greaterThanTen, the_list)`.

If you want to sort by the value at index 1 for each element in the list, you can do this:

```
filter(lambda element: yourSortFunction(elmenet[1]), list)
```

This is similar to the function you're using as a key to sort.

**Another another thing:** Why are you trying to call `the_list` in **`greaterThanTen`**, it makes no sense. The function stops evaluating code after the `return` statement.

**Printing:**

If you want to print a value from a specific index in a list just ask for that index.

> print(LIST[index])

**I hope this helps.**

Comment: I liked my solution as much simpler, but yours is far more complete and provides good documentation, so +1

Comment: so what you are telling me is this code will reorder my list according to my specifications?

def greaterThanTen(index):
    return index > 10
the_list = filter(greaterThanTen,the_list)

no need for sorting at this point, just categorizing.

Comment: @Joseph Good catch. There's no need to sort, you're right. **Filter only returns those items for which `yourSortFunction` returns True.**

Answer (score 0):

You could probably just do some sort of list comprehension and avoid filtering altogether.

```
the_final_list = [x for x in the_list if x[1] < 10]
```

This to me is simpler/more readable and accomplishes your objective.

Comment: and to print this it would be something along the lines of print "Small States Include:" (the_final_list)  , i guess similarly for big states, i would just change the operator to greater than and print for similar results? This code seems to allow me to remove the def and filter function, correct?

Comment: You'll end up with a list that looks just like your current the_list which you can use however you wish. And correct, you could safely remove your filter line and your filter function. You could do `small_states = [x for x in the_list if x[1] < 10]` and `large_states = [x for x in the_list if x[1] > 20]` or whatever numbers you wanted